# Cascading items in a collection of a component

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, components

I have a component which contains a collection.  I can't seem to get NHibernate to persist items in the collection if I have the collection marked as Inverse.   They will persist if I don't have Inverse on the collection, but I get an insert and then an update statement.

My mapping is :

```
m => m.Component(x => x.Configuration, c =>
{
  c.HasMany(x => x.ObjectiveTitleTemplates)
    .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
    .AsSet()
    //.Inverse()
    .KeyColumns.Add("ObjectiveProcessInstanceId")
    .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();                                                               
});
```

Is there a way to get it working marking the collection as Inverse and therefore avoiding the extra insert?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Mapping the collection as inverse is not enough. You have to:

- Create a Reference from the "Many" side
- Update it when adding elements to the collection

When you use `Inverse`, NHibernate does not persist the relationship from that side.